# Convert lat long into address using NuGet

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am developing a windows phone application which requires to convert the current latitude and longitude into the address on the map.
how to convert a Geo-coordinate to address pointing to the map using GoogleMaps.LocationServices Nu Get package.

Comment: Why so many different tags :O asp.net, wpf, windows-phone-8 What are you developing for?

Comment: as i have mentioned i am developing a windows phone application.

Comment: @Xyroid:can u please help on this ?

Comment: Why use google maps? There is a built in API for this in Windows Phone 8 with the [ReverseGeocodeQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.services.reversegeocodequery(v=vs.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

GoogleMaps.LocationServices NuGet package doesn't have method to find street address. Try the below code.

```
const string API_ADDRESS_FROM_LATLONG = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng={0},{1}&sensor=false";

public void GetAddressFromLatLong(string Lat, string Long)
{
    try 
    {           
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(string.Format(API_ADDRESS_FROM_LATLONG, Lat, Long)));
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += webClient_DownloadStringCompleted;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}

void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
        var Address = doc.Descendants("result").FirstOrDefault().Descendants("formatted_address").FirstOrDefault().Value;
        MessageBox.Show(Address);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```